# add memo contents to database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

Got a cxmemo1 that I need to add its contents to database.
Right now all I add is the first line:

```
ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('A2').VALUE := CXMEMO1.text;
```

I know I need to modify this line but how ?
I want all lines in the memo to be entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in that code that should be preventing multiple lines from being posted to the DB.  So either the `cxMemo.Text` property is not returning all of the text in the first place, or the DB is truncating the field text on the first line break.

Comment: unfortunately it functions that way ... :(  maybe cxmemo.lines.add might do the trick ?

Comment: what is strange is that the text actually get written in the database (its MEMO type). However the cx grid is showing me only the first line.If I make its property a blobedit (blomeditkind=memo) then there's no problem. But I need to see the contents.

Comment: Then the problem is with the `cxGrid`, not the `cxMemo` or the DB. My guess (I have never used cxGrid) is that there is a property you can set to see the extra lines. Maybe the `OptionsView.CellAutoHeight` property?